# Drupal 7.. add link in block

Tags: drupal-7

I am using drupal 7 and working in my localhost/mydrupal
I want to add a link in a custom block
I wrote

```
<p><a href="/">Home</a> | <a href="/user">Connect</a></p>
```

On click to Home I am in **localhost/** instead of **localhost/mydrupal**
and on click to Connect I am in **localhost/user** instead of **localhost/mydrupal/user**

Any idea please to correct this?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi you can use $base_url for this
<code>
Example :
<?php
global $base_url;
?>
<p><a href="<?php print $base_url;?>">Home</a> | <a href="<?php print $base_url;?>/user">Connect</a></p>
</code>
```